# Отключение checkbox-а другим checkbox

Tags: html, css, checkbox

Есть два `checkbox`, нужно чтобы при нажатии на первый, второй отключался(или еще другие, к примеру).
В данном случае у меня работает только в одну сторону. Из-за очередности html.
То бишь, так как `input`/`label` первого стоит выше, то он и работает, второй не реагирует. JS не знаю, поэтому пытаюсь собрать велосипед из палок.

Вопрос: Можно ли посредством CSS реализовать сие или нужно прибегать к скриптам?

```css
input, label {
  display: inline-block;
}
/* 1 > 2 */
#ch-areas:checked ~ .sh-islands {
  pointer-events: none;
}

#ch-areas:checked ~ .sh-islands .tx-islands {
  color: grey !important;
}

/* 2 > 1 */
#islands:checked ~ .sh-areas {
  pointer-events: none;
}

#ch-areas:checked ~ .sh-areas .tx-areas {
  color: grey !important;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="show-areas checkbox" id="ch-areas" />
<label for="ch-areas" class="sh-areas"><span class="label-text tx-areas">1</span></label>
  <br>
<input type="checkbox" class="show-islands checkbox" id="islands" />
<label for="islands" class="sh-islands"><span class="label-text tx-islands">2</span></label>
```

Comment: может для этой задачи лучше подойдет элемент radio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предлагаю вот такое решение, от выбора какого другого чекбокса задизейблится конкретный чекбокс вписано в классы

```js
let cb = [...document.querySelectorAll('.cb')];
let change = e => e.disabled = cb.filter(c => c.checked && e.classList.contains(c.id)).length
cb.forEach(c => c.onchange = () => cb.forEach(change))
```

```css
* {
  user-select:none;
}

input {
  display:none;
}

label {
  font-size: 40px;
  border: solid;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px ;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[disabled] + label {
  color: gray;
  cursor: default;
  pointer-events: none;
}

input:checked + label {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input id="cb1" type="checkbox" class="cb cb4 cb3"><label for="cb1">1</label>
<input id="cb2" type="checkbox" class="cb cb4 cb3"><label for="cb2">2</label>
<input id="cb3" type="checkbox" class="cb cb1 cb2"><label for="cb3">3</label>
<input id="cb4" type="checkbox" class="cb cb1 cb2"><label for="cb4">4</label>
```

Comment: вы сначала объясните, что такой код (ES6) не запустится просто так. Нужно сначала бабелем собрать.

Comment: @AlexeyKapustsin не запустится в internet explorer? )

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Ваш способ работает и как раз то, что нужно. Только вот на деле `input` у меня скрыты, обработка идет через `label`. Как я понял Ваш скрипт приписывает атрибут `disabled`, но работает он только в `input`. Можно, чтобы к лейблам добавлялось `style="pointer-events: none;`? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @IlliaMei да конечно, только код я поправлю попозже, убежал от компа

Comment: @IlliaMei я добавил label в пример и клики по ним не действуют, если чекбокс задизейблен, Вы их верно добавляете?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ да, виноват, забыл сменить `label=for"x"`. Все классно, спасибо. Однако, нашел недочет, но мне он не мешает. Если активировать, `1`, затем `2` и снова(отменить) `2`, то `3` и `4` становятся доступны, при активной `1`.

Comment: @IlliaMei исправил

Comment: @StrangerintheQ забыл упомянуть насчет присваивания к `label` - `style="pointer-events: none;"` или сразу какой-либо определенный class. Это долго менять?

Comment: @IlliaMei нет не долго, а зачем? что-то не так работает?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ у меня `input` скрыты, кликабельны `label`. Все отлично работает, но когда присваивается атрибут `disabled` к `input`, визуально лейблы не меняются, разве что не переключаются, пока не попробуешь.

Comment: @IlliaMei понял, вы хотите отобразить состояние

Comment: @IlliaMei посмотрите обновление, может так подойдет?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ да, спасибо, не догадался так сделать :)  Извините за беспокойство.

Comment: @IlliaMei нет пооблем

Answer (score 0):

Для этого обычно используются [radio-butoon](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/radio).

Просто [поменяйте их отображение средствами CSS](http://dimox.name/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons-using-css-only/)

Comment: Что если нужно делать очередные действия, нажал один чекбокс задисайбелись некоторые другие, не все например, а при нажатии на другой задисейбелись некоторые из тех которые уже были в дисайбле, только не все, тогда радио будет не актуально. Вопрос про чекбоксы, а не радио кнопки. Но есть шанс, что @IlliaMei просто не понимает, что он делает!

Comment: @And что не понимаю, к примеру? А radio не подойдет, т.к. у меня не опросник, а карта, на которой отображаются/отключаются объекты.

Comment: @IlliaMei, Вот почему я и говорил =) Что радио не подойдет. а вам следует создавать вопрос более правильно и описывать задачу подробнее. Дополните в вопрос подробное описание, того, что хотите и что у вас уже есть. Чтобы было понятно, что вы делаете. И да, попробуйте использовать псевдо-класс `:disabled `. Но все-же есть шанс, что сделать этого не удастся без скрипта или аттрибута.

Comment: @IlliaMei в таком случаем вам придётся прибегнуть к использованию JavaScript

Comment: @And Честно, не совсем понимаю куда, зачем и что даст мне конкретно `:disabled`? По факту: если 1 включен - 2 выключен, и наоборот.

Comment: @AlexeyKapustsin плохо, это было ожидаемо. )

Comment: @IlliaMei, Плохо чем? Тем, что вы не знаете `JS`? Однозначно =)